# how do I restore my account after upgrade to 11.10

Tags: 11.10, upgrade

I upgraded my ubuntu OS from 11.04 to 11.10 a few days ago. During this process the update manager alerted me that it encountered some errors, and suggested I send a bug report. I tried to send it, but somehow there wasn't an internet connection anymore so I couldn't send it after all.

After I rebooted, the login screen seemed to be okay, but the second time I logged in to my account and ever since I only see the desktop background without any panels. I can't add a screenshot but basically on top of the desktop image it shows all the options of nautilus (bookmarks, edit, ...)

It has to be something specificaly wrong this account, because when I open the guest account, it has everything there.

Is there any way to solve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like unity may have got a bit broken on upgrade. You can try fixing it by opening a terminal and typing:

```
unity --reset
```

If it doesn't work, please add the output of that command to your question.

Also it might be worth uninstalling the nautilus-open-terminal package if you had it installed - this caused compiz crashes ([launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/865115)) which might lead to your problems. The fix is currently in the oneiric-proposed repository, and should be generally available soon, but not quite yet.

Alternatively, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67413/unity-launcher-missing-top-panel-changed-colour-no-controls-on-the-right-hand/68915#68915) suggests:

> I found the workaround [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11314525&postcount=8):
>
> ```
> sudo rm /usr/share/GConf/gsettings/pythonconsole.convert
> gsettings-data-convert
> gnome-settings-daemon
> ```
>
> Then, to solve definitely at every login, I had to create a launcher
>   to *gnome-settings-daemon* in my home folder and add it to my startup
>   applications.